# Incremental counter if the value is the same before the point

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following STRING column on a pandas DataFrame.

```
HOURCENTSEG(string-column)
070026.16169
070026.16169
070026.16169
070026.16169
070052.85555
070052.85555
070109.43620
070202.56430
070202.56431
070202.56434
070202.56434
```

As you can see we have many elements where the time overlaps before the point, in all the fields to avoid date overlaps I must add an incremental counter as I show you in the following output example.

```
HOURCENTSEG (string-column)
070026.00001
070026.00002
070026.00003
070026.00004
070052.00001
070052.00002
070109.00001  (if there is only one value it's just 00001)
070202.00001
070202.00002
070202.00003
070202.00004
```

It is a poorly designed application in the past and I have no other option to solve this.

Summary: Add an incremental counter after point. With a maximum size of 5, and padded with 0 from the left, When the number to the left of the point is equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with splitted values by `.` and selected first sublist, last add zeros by [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
s = df['HOURCENTSEG'].str.split('.').str[0]
df['HOURCENTSEG'] = s + '.' + s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(5)
print (df)
     HOURCENTSEG
0   070026.00001
1   070026.00002
2   070026.00003
3   070026.00004
4   070052.00001
5   070052.00002
6   070109.00001
7   070202.00001
8   070202.00002
9   070202.00003
10  070202.00004
```